# Product Recommendation Approach on the basis of purchase history in R

Tags: r

I have super market data(users with their transactions history). In which i want to recommend the product to the user on the basis of purchase history like Market basket Analysis. But in "**Arules - Market Basket Analysis**", we perform the operation only on Transaction data but i want to do this with user also. So that if any user logged-in i can recommend new product based on purchase history as well as transaction history.

Please let me know how can i implement this in R.

Comment: You can use the **purchased product** code by a customer as a **key** to get the associated products in the market basket analysis table and show as recommendations. There are a lot of ways to make recommendations which depends on the objective you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am new to R and I have to do some POC with small project.
Let me explain you my requirement: 
Customer A Purchase -> LG Brand -> Mobile, 
Customer B Purchase -> Sony Brand -> Camera,
Customer C Purchase -> LG Brand -> Mobile, Headphone,

Requirement:
1)If Customer A again visit the site then we need to recommend LG brand Headphone.
2)If Customer B again visit the site then we need to recommend Sony brand related items/camera.


Please let me know your thoughts on this.